# How to add a hook into a zap logger?

Tags: go, go-zap

I try to add hook with `WithOptions` but there was nothing printed for catching some of log events:

```golang
    logger.WithOptions(zap.Hooks(func(entry zapcore.Entry) error {
        fmt.Println("test hooks test hooks")
        return nil
    }))
```

Comment: Did you, by any chance, forget to `defer logger.Sync()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#Logger.WithOptions):

```golang
func (log *Logger) WithOptions(opts ...Option) *Logger
```

> WithOptions **clones** the current Logger, applies the supplied Options, and returns the resulting Logger. It's safe to use concurrently.

Notice that it clones a new logger instead of modifying the logger. So, you should reassign the logger variable (or define a new variable) like this:

```golang
logger = logger.WithOptions(zap.Hooks(func(entry zapcore.Entry) error {
    fmt.Println("test hooks test hooks")
    return nil
}))
```